# Get adjacent ways Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm new to Overpass API and I need an Overpass QL query that gets a way of type highway by osm_id and also gets the previous and the next way. By previous way I mean all ways with type highway whose last node is the same as the first node of the original way. And with next way I mean all ways whose first node are the same as the last node of the original way.

I have tried (with the help of Chat GPT admittedly) the following query:

```
[out:json];

way(805290645)->.way;

node(w.way.nodes[0])->.first;
node(w.way.nodes[-1])->.last;


way(around:0.1, .first.last, meta)["highway"]->.next;
way(around:0.1, .last.first, meta)["highway"]->.prev;

(
  way(805290645);
  .next;
  .prev;
);
out meta;
```

But this returns only the 'original way' `way(805290645)`. Like this:

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.59 e21c39fe",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2023-02-24T12:38:23Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 805290645,
  "timestamp": "2022-10-05T00:46:15Z",
  "version": 10,
  "changeset": 127021576,
  "user": "A67-A67",
  "uid": 553736,
  "nodes": [
    44390230,
    9802326146,
    2935854435,
    9802326142,
    9904639298,
    9904639299,
    3946339905,
    5768131540
  ],
  "tags": {
    "access:lanes": "no|no|yes|yes",
    "carriageway_ref": "Li",
    "highway": "motorway",
    "int_ref": "E 25",
    "lanes": "4",
    "maxspeed": "100",
    "maxspeed:conditional": "130 @ (19:00-06:00)",
    "noname": "yes",
    "official_name": "Rijksweg nr 20",
    "oneway": "yes",
    "operator": "Rijkswaterstaat",
    "overtaking:hgv:conditional": "no @ (Mo-Fr 06:00-19:00)",
    "ref": "A20",
    "source:official_name": "BAG;NWB",
    "surface": "asphalt",
    "turn:lanes": "slight_left|slight_left|slight_right|slight_right"
  }
}

  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following as starting point, which isn't exactly what you've asked for, but way better what ChatGPT offers as a solution (which is in fact invalid Overpass QL syntax):

```
way(805290645);
node(w:1,-1);      // get first and last node of way
out;               // print first / last node
way(bn)[highway];  // find highway=* ways which include first/last node
out geom;          // print those ways
```

You can also filter out way 805290645:

```
way(805290645)->.w;
node(w.w:1,-1);     
out;              
(way(bn)[highway]; - way.w;);
out geom;
```

Getting adjacent ways can also be accomplished by using the *complete* statement. This github issue highlights a few use cases: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/95